# if $\lim{x_n} = 0$ and $x_n < 0$ then $\lim \frac{1}{x_n} = - \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove $\lim\frac{1}{x_n} = -\infty$ if $x_n < 0$ and $\lim x_n=0$

Is this proof correct.

$\lim x_n=0$ thus, given $x_n < 0$
$$
\forall \epsilon > 0 \, \exists N : \forall n > N \, : -\epsilon < x_n < \epsilon \implies -\epsilon < x_{n} < 0$$

Let $z > 0$  and define $\epsilon = \frac{1}{z} < 0$

From $\lim x_{n}=0$
$$\exists N = M_{\frac{1}{z}} \, : \forall n > M_{\frac{1}{z}} \implies \frac{-1}{z} < x_{n} < 0 \implies \frac{-1}{x_{n}} < z$$

and so
$$\forall z > 0 \exists M : \forall n > M = M_{\frac{1}{z}} \implies \frac{-1}{x_{n}} < z $$

and so $\lim \frac{1}{x_n} = -\infty$

Comment: You can use Latex in the title too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the inequality backwards in the last two equations.
$$\frac{-1}{z} < x_n < 0 \implies \frac{-1}{x_n} > z,$$
because you have divided by $x_n < 0$. Then you get $\frac{1}{x_n} < -z$ which is really what you want.